# How to make db tables for product filters?

Tags: mysql, sql, sorting

I want to create **product filter for multiple categories**. User will select for ex. Mobile phones category via form select element and then there will be showed options for this category which user can choose, for ex. Color, processor,...

And I want to know how best way how to set up database tables for this purpose. My idea is to create three tables:

```
1. Items
Id | Item_Name   | Cat_Id | Option_1 | Option_2 | ... 
1  | Samsung S20 | 1      | blue     | Intel    | ...
2  | iPhone 5    | 1      | red      | AMD      | ...
3  | T-shirt     | 2      | red      | NULL     | ...

2. Categories:
Id | Cat_Name | 
1  | mobiles  | 
2  | clothes  | 

3. Options
Id | Option    | Values                 |
1  | color     | red, blue, purple, ... |      
2  | processor | Intel, AMD, ...        |

4. Cats_Opts
Id | Cat_id | Option_id |
1  | 1      | 1         | 
2  | 1      | 2         |
```

Problem is, that in my structure many fields will be empty bcz for ex. clothes category will not have value for option_2.

Is this good way how to do db structure for this purpose?

Comment: A database is normalized when there's a single column for each type of information. So when you see more than one column having the same information, that part of the database is not "normalized". In the case of columns `Option_1` and `Option_2`, to normalize these duplicated columns create another `Item_Options` table, and link to it with an `item_id`. That table would have columns: `item_option_id`, `item_id`, and `option`.

Comment: I agree with the above answer. What you need is a parametring table which contains 2 columns referencing : Items.Id and Options.Id
This way you are able to add as many options as you wish to an item

Comment: Similarly when you see lists of data in a column, such as `red, blue, purple` in a single column, this may be a candidate for normalization. (Not to say there is no place for "un-normalized" data in a relational database.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A database is [normalized](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization), at least in part, when there's a single column for each type of information. So when you see more than one column having the same information, that part of the database is not "normalized".

Similarly when you see lists of data in a column, such as `red, blue, purple` in a single column, this is a candidate for normalization. (Not to say there is no place for "un-normalized" data in a relational database.)

```
1. Items
| Id | Item_Name   | Cat_Id |
| 1  | Samsung S20 | 1      |
| 2  | iPhone 5    | 1      |
| 3  | T-shirt     | 2      |

2. Item_Color_Options
| Item_Id | Color  |
| 1       | blue   |
| 1       | red    |
| 2       | blue   |
| 3       | purple |

3. Item_Processor_Options
| Item_Id | Processor |
| 1       | Intel     |
| 1       | AMD       |
| 2       | Intel     |
```

Another opportunity for normalization is when a column has the same data repeated in more than one rows, such as:

```
| Item_Id | Color  |
| 1       | blue   |
| 1       | red    |
| 2       | blue   |
| 3       | purple |

// and

| Item_Id | Processor |
| 1       | Intel     |
| 1       | AMD       |
| 2       | Intel     |
```

...where `blue` and `Intel` are repeated.

In this case, and particularly when the same value or option may be applied to more that one item, the duplicated options can be eliminated using linking tables:

```
// primary tables

1. Items
| Id | Item_Name   | Cat_Id |
| 1  | Samsung S20 | 1      |
| 2  | iPhone 5    | 1      |
| 3  | T-shirt     | 2      |

2. Categories
| Id | Cat_Name | 
| 1  | mobiles  | 
| 2  | clothes  | 


// option tables

3. Color_Options
| Id | Color       |
| 1  | red         |
| 2  | blue        |
| 3  | purple      |

4. Processor_Options
| Id | Processor       |
| 1  | Intel           |
| 2  | AMC             |


// linking tables

5. Item_Color_Options
| Item_Id | Color_Id |
| 1       | 1        |
| 1       | 2        |
| 2       | 1        |
| 2       | 3        |

6. Item_Processor_Options
| Item_Id | Processor_Id |
| 1       | 1            |
| 2       | 2            |
| 3       | 1            |

4. Cats_Opts
| Id | Cat_id | Option_id |
| 1  | 1      | 1         | 
| 2  | 1      | 2         |
```

To compile all the options into fewer reference tables:

```
Option_Types
| Id | Option    |
| 1  | Color     |
| 2  | Processor |
| 3  | Other     |

Options_Values
| Id | Option_Types_Id | Value       |
| 1  | 1               | red         |
| 1  | 1               | blue        |
| 1  | 1               | purple      |
| 2  | 2               | Intel       |
| 2  | 2               | AMD         |

Item_Options
| Item_Id | Option_Values_Id |
| 1       | 5                |
| 2       | 4                |
| 3       | 2                |
```

Then, of course, [`JOIN`](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp) them all together.

```
-- create
CREATE TABLE Items (
  Id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
  Item_Name TEXT NOT NULL,
  Category_Id INTEGER NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE Categories (
  Id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
  Cat_Name TEXT NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE Option_Types (
  Id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
  `Option` TEXT NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE Option_Values (
  Id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
  Option_Types_Id INTEGER NOT NULL,
  Value TEXT NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE Item_Options (
  Items_Id INTEGER NOT NULL,
  Option_Values_Id INTEGER NOT NULL
);

-- insert
INSERT INTO Items VALUES (1, 'Samsung S20', 1), (2, 'iPhone 5', 1), (3, 'T-shirt', 2);
INSERT INTO Categories VALUES (1, 'mobiles'), (2, 'clothes');
INSERT INTO Option_Types VALUES (1, 'Color'), (2, 'Processor');
INSERT INTO Option_Values VALUES (1, 1, 'red'), (2, 1, 'blue'), (3, 1, 'purple'), (4, 2, 'Intel'), (5, 2, 'AMD');
INSERT INTO Item_Options VALUES (1, 5), (2, 4), (3, 2);

-- fetch 
SELECT Items.Id, Items.Item_Name, Categories.Cat_Name, Option_Types.`Option`, Option_Values.Value
  FROM Items
  LEFT JOIN Categories ON Items.Category_Id = Categories.Id
  LEFT JOIN Item_Options ON Items.Id = Item_Options.Items_Id
  LEFT JOIN Option_Values ON Item_Options.Option_Values_Id = Option_Values.Id
  LEFT JOIN Option_Types ON Option_Values.Option_Types_Id = Option_Types.Id
;
```

Outputs:

| Id | Item_Name | Cat_Name | Option | Value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Samsung S20 | mobiles | Processor | AMD |
| 2 | iPhone 5 | mobiles | Processor | Intel |
| 3 | T-shirt | clothes | Color | blue |

Try it here: https://onecompiler.com/mysql/3yj627ggs

Comment: Thank you for very clear explanation. I have just one question. Will not be problem that there will be maybe 300 options (color, processor, RAM, memory, width, ....) totaly. If each option need separate table, is it ok for speed of filtering based on options?

Comment: I don't know, but do not think 300 tables is a major problem for a modern database server. Although it's not difficult to reduced that to two tables. I updated my answer.

Comment: bloodyKnuckles - I add my understaning of result like answer, I hope I understand it correctly.

Comment: I added a working example to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

So if I can summary it, finally, it can look like this:

```
// primary tables

1. Items
| Id | Item_Name   | Cat_Id |
| 1  | Samsung S20 | 1      |
| 2  | iPhone 5    | 1      |
| 3  | T-shirt     | 2      |

2. Categories
| Id | Cat_Name | 
| 1  | mobiles  | 
| 2  | clothes  | 


// Options tables

3. Option_Types
| Id | Option_Type |
| 1  | Color       |
| 2  | Processor   |
| 3  | Other       |

4. Option_Values
| Option_Type_Id | Option_Value |
| 1              | red          |
| 1              | blue         |
| 1              | purple       |
| 2              | Intel        |
| 2              | AMD          |

// Summary table

5. Items_Options
| Item_Id | Option_Type_Id | Option_Value_ID |
| 1       | 1              | 1               |
| 1       | 2              | 1               |
| 2       | 1              | 2               |
```

Comment: That looks like it will work. Although I don't see the need to repeat the `Option_Type_Id` column in the `Items_Options` table.